# Decomposing the difference of products of N terms

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\Delta = \prod_{i\le N}x_{1i} - \prod_{i\le N} x_{2i}$ for some N.

I want to 'decompose' the $\Delta$ into sum of N components in the form of

$$\Delta = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \{\prod_{j=1}^{N} x_{k_{ij},j} - \prod_{j=1}^{N} x_{l_{ij}, j}\}$$

where the indices $k_{ij}$ and $l_{ij}$ take value of either 1 or 2 and must have $k_{ii} = 1$ and $l_{ii} = 2$ for all $i$, and $k_{ij} = l_{ij}$ if $i \neq j$.

For example, in the case of $N=3$, I can do
$$\Delta = (x_{11}x_{12}x_{13} - x_{21}x_{22}x_{23}) = (x_{11}x_{12}x_{13} - x_{21}x_{12}x_{13}) + (x_{21}x_{12}x_{13} - x_{21}x_{22}x_{13}) + (x_{21}x_{22}x_{13} - x_{21}x_{22}x_{23})$$

and I think I have 6 different ways to do the decomposition. My conjecture is that there are $N!$ different ways to do the decomposition. Can anyone confirm my hypothesis and lay out a way to represent all the combinations?

Specifically, I want to get the form of

$$\Delta = \frac{1}{N!} \sum_{i}^N(x_{1i}-x_{2i})(\cdots)$$

by summing up all possible decompositions and divide it by the number of combinations, where the dots are sum of $N!$ products of $(N-1)$ terms. There are $2^{(N-1)}$ combinations of products, which is far smaller than $N!$ and $N!$ is not divisible by $2^{(N-1)}$. So I guess there is some other way to represent the dots. I found a formula that works up to $N=4$, but that doesn't work beyond. Is there a way to express the dots for general $N$?

The formula I found was

$$(\cdots)_i = \{\prod_{j \neq i} (x_{1j} + x_{2j}) + K(\prod_{j \neq i} x_{1j} + \prod_{j \neq i} x_{2j})\} \cdot \frac{N!}{2^{N-1} + 2K}$$

where $K = 2^{N-3}$ if $N\ge3$ and 0 otherwise.

It seems to be exact for $N \le 4$ and gives pretty decent approximation beyond $N>4$ at least for the range of numbers that I'm mostly interested in.

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit than $(...)$. Please give your formulas for $N=2$ and $N=3$ at least.

Comment: Updated my formula. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to tell us what your **goal** is. Why do you need an alternate expression for $\Delta$ which seems simple enough as defined? Help us help you by telling us what problem you want to solve.

Comment: I want to have a breakdown of $\Delta$ by change of individual components. There are many ways to 'bridge' the gap as you said and they all result in different answers in terms of the individual contribution. I want to get a 'fair' attribution by taking average of all of the ways to bridge the gap. The average might not be intuitively appealing, and there are easy and intuitive ways to do the same exercise, but I want to at least explore how it works. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Your hypothesis is true. You can think of the problem as
a string mutation one. That is, beginning with a string
of $N$ `1` characters, you change one character at a time
from `1` to `2` in any order until all of the $N$ characters
are changed to `2`s. In your example, the sequence of changes
in the order $1,2,3$ is

```
111 -> 211 -> 221 -> 222
```

and similarly for any order of character changes. There are
clearly $\,N!\,$ such orderings, one for each permutation of
$\,1,2,\dots,N.\,$

Comment: That really helps! But I want to obtain a specific form after summing up all the combinations. I edited the question, could you take a look? Thank you very much!